# how to run hbase sample data script "index-builder-setup.rb"?

Tags: ruby, mapreduce, hbase

> hbase-0.94.0/src/examples/mapreduce/index-builder-setup.rb
>   when i run the script,it reports error:
>   [zhouhh@Hadoop48 mapreduce]$ ruby index-builder-setup.rb
>   index-builder-setup.rb:18: undefined method `create' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
>   index-builder-setup.rb:

```
# Set up sample data for IndexBuilder example
create "people", "attributes"
create "people-email", "INDEX"
create "people-phone", "INDEX"
create "people-name", "INDEX"

[["1", "jenny", "jenny@example.com", "867-5309"],
 ["2", "alice", "alice@example.com", "555-1234"],
 ["3", "kevin", "kevinpet@example.com", "555-1212"]].each do |fields|
  (id, name, email, phone) = *fields
  put "people", id, "attributes:name", name
  put "people", id, "attributes:email", email
  put "people", id, "attributes:phone", phone
end
```

Comment: I have found the answer,please reference my blog,but you may use google translate : http://abloz.com/2012/07/03/the-hbase-how-implementation-of-the-ruby-script.html

Comment: It would be great to include a brief summary of the solution here, to guard against link rot.

Comment: @user1095131, the link you specified is dead.

Answer (score 3):

We should not use ruby for this, since it didn't know what is hbase.

For you case, try this:

`./bin/hbase shell /path-to-your-hbase-dir/src/examples/mapreduce/index-builder-setup.rb`